# In the Star Trek Universe, what is the value of Gold in the 24th Century?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-ds9

ST TNG "The Last Outpost":

> KAYRON: You see? They are demented. Their values are insane. You
>   cannot believe the business opportunities they have destroyed.
>
> LETEK: Proof of their barbarism. **They adorn themselves with gold, a
>   despicable use of a valuable metal**. And they shamelessly clothe their
>   females.
>
> MORDOC: Inviting others to unclothe them. The very depth of
>   perversion.

ST DS9 "Little Green Men":

> QUARK: Dollars? Never heard of them. Don't you have any gemstones or
>   precious minerals?
>
> DENNING: You mean like gold?
>
> QUARK: **Gold? Gold is good**.
>
> DENNING: How much gold are we talking about?

DS9 "Who Mourns for Morn":

> QUARK: Beautiful, isn't it? And the way it picks up the light I wonder
>   who came up with the idea of suspending liquid latinum inside
>   **worthless bits of gold**?
>
> DAX: Probably somebody who got tired of making change with an
>   eyedropper. Are you going to play or not?

DS9 "Who Mourns for Morn":

> QUARK: That can't be! There's no latinum in these bricks!
>
> ODO: What?
>
> QUARK: Someone's extracted all the latinum. **There's nothing here but
>   worthless gold.**
>
> ODO: And it's all yours.
>
> QUARK: No! No! No!

DS9 "Who Mourns for Morn":

> (Morn looks around, picks up a glass and regurgitates a drop of
>   glistening mercury-like liquid.)
>
> QUARK: Of course. Your second stomach. You've been keeping it in your
>   second stomach all these years? That's a lot of latinum. No wonder
>   your hair fell out.
>
> (Morn gives Quark the glass.)
>
> QUARK: For me? That must be a hundred bricks worth. I don't know what
>   to say. Thanks. Not that I didn't earn it after all you put me
>   through. If you ever want to set me up again, feel free. You know, you
>   and I should consider doing business together. Two enterprising
>   gentlemen like us could do all right for ourselves. **Take that gold
>   dust of yours. It doesn't have to be a total loss. I hear there're
>   some primitive cultures who consider it quite valuable.**

This is somewhat confusing.  My question is: **What is the value of Gold in the 24th century?** Is it still considered a precious metal?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6923/how-to-reconcile-the-cashless-human-federation-society-with-human-traders-and-me

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92082/how-do-people-in-the-federation-know-how-much-they-own-if-there-is-no-money/92084#92084

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92180/are-all-federation-members-part-of-the-same-cashless-economy/92200#92200

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67930/what-is-economics-like-for-ordinary-people-in-the-star-trek-universe

Comment: @calccrypto I've actually posted answers to two of those questions. Thanks for pointing them out. My question isn't if there's currency, I'm specifically trying to figure out about gold. It appears that there's conflicting dialogue in various episodes about gold being a precious metal to it being worthless, and everything in between. Just wanted clarity on the value of gold in the 24th century.

Comment: Yeah. That's why I didn't flag this as a dupe.

Answer (score 16):

## It's quite worthless

As per [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gold):

> Though once considered very valuable, by the 23rd century **the
>   Federation considered [gold] almost worthless, except for decorative and
>   functional purposes**. (TOS: "Catspaw"; TNG: "The Last Outpost", "Time's
>   Arrow"; VOY: "Muse")

However, that is the Federation; the Ferengi still considered it valuable up until fairly late in the 24th century:

> Dialogue in TNG: "The Last Outpost" and "The Perfect Mate" suggested
>   that, **at least as late as 2368, Ferengi considered gold valuable**. In
>   "Little Green Men", Quark says to a 20th-century Human that "gold is
>   good" while discussing what humans could trade for advanced Ferengi
>   technology. **However, by the time of "Who Mourns for Morn?", Quark
>   described gold as "worthless"**, seemingly contradicting the earlier
>   assessment that gold had "good" trade value.

The reason for this, as explained in Philipp's answer above, is probably **the replicator**

> One explanation for this apparent devaluation of gold was the fact
>   that **the Ferengi had only recently made First Contact with the
>   Federation. Replicator technology, if introduced to a gold-based
>   economy, could send markets plunging.** This may have happened to the
>   Ferengi, who would have experienced a massive gold market crash as a
>   result. Then again, gold may have lost value for some other reason.
>   **The comment in "Little Green Men" may be in the context of a
>   pre-replicator economy, especially since he stated his intention not
>   to go back to his own time, remaining in the past and ruling the Earth
>   within a year.**

Comment: Nice work @N_Soong, very complete! +1  I just placed a comment below the other answer that's very similar to the end of your answer (without having seen it in your answer).  One of us is using his synaptic scanner again... ;-)

Comment: In "Little Green Men" Quark said "gold is good" because most likely it was the only resource humans could've given them in sufficient weight - "gold is good" as in "we'll be satisfied in half your planet's supply" - it's like paying for a LED TV with quarters

Comment: Kind of like what happened to aluminum: http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/elements/features/2010/blogging_the_periodic_table/aluminum_it_used_to_be_more_precious_than_gold.html

Comment: Also, @Petersaber, Ferengi understand fiat currencies. Offering Quark a million greenbacks would be pointless, it depends on the full faith and credit of a government he doesn't want to be bound to.  Gold, as a commodity valued in pre-replicator society, would be fungible, useful with all nations on Earth, almost all cultures, without worrying about fiddly things like currency conversion.  Finally, commodities cannot be traced.  You can't PROVE that brick of gold came from the USSR, not once it's remelted into a new mold.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to replicator technology, most common elements can be created from energy, making them practically worthless as a trade commodity. Gold is one of these.

The only resources which still have value are those which can not be replicated, like Dilithium or Latinum.

Comment: Well, sure, we know that. So what's the story with the scripts quoted above that talk about gold as if it's valuable?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Bad writing. Star trek writers often forget the implications of replicator technology.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill : With respect to the "Little Green Men" episode of *DS9*, Quark said earlier in the episode that, if they couldn't get back to their own time, he would stay on Earth and attempt to rule it within a year, using his knowledge of the future.  If that was indeed his plan, then gold would have been valuable to him as it was a precious commodity on Earth in the 20th Century.

Comment: @Praxis Yes, exactly.  Ferengi are traders, so whatever is valuable they will be trying to trade and acquire, whether it's gold, latium, or self sealing stembolts.